# How to add a label and image view to a toolbar and set the properties in code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uitoolbar

I would like to show a label (`UILabel` and an image view (`UIMageView`) on a toolbar (`UIToolbar`). In Interface Builder, I have added a bar button item (`UIBarButtonItem`) for each of these views and have dragged an empty view (`UIView`) on each of the bar button items. Please refer to the screenshot below for the view hierarchy.

[image]

I assume that each of these views have become `customViews` which I should be able to access in code with

`UIView *labelBarButtonView = (UIView*)labelBarButtonItem.customView;`

and then access the label or image view with

`UILabel *companyLabel = (UILabel*)[labelBarButtonItem.customView viewWithTag:tag];`

However, when running the code, my app crashes with the error message: `'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView customView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

What did I miss? What would be a better way to create the views in Interface Builder and access their properties in code?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you need to connect the view to the customView outlet of the Bar Button Item in IB.

Comment: Jamihash, it is not possible to connect these views in IB.

Comment: @AlexR, unless you are doing something really weird you should be able to connect IBOutlets to these views in your UIToolBar just like any other view. I do it quite often, unless I am misunderstanding something in your description.

Comment: Joel, I can connect the views in the toolbar directly to my code. However, I tried to connect only the toolbar as an outlet to the code and access the toolbar's child views using `viewWithTag:`, which does not work in my set-up above.

Comment: @AlexR I just do not understand the motivation. Also why are you using `.customView` to reach the subviews? You should be able to just call: `UILabel *compnayLabel = [self.myToolBar viewWithTag:1]` (lastly, I do not get an inbox notification unless you put an @ before my username)

Comment: @Joel, this call did not work for me. I understood that I have to put label and images inside a `UIBarButtonItem` in order to be displayed correctly on a toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Alright I think this is your issue. In the line of code:

```
UIView *labelBarButtonView = (UIView*)labelBarButtonItem.customView;
```

You are actually casting `labelBarButtonItem` into a `UIView` then requesting the `customView` from it. It seems like you would be casting `customView`but you are not. So try using this code:

```
UIView *labelBarButtonView = (UIView*)((UIBarButtonItem *)labelBarButtonItem.customView);
```

The above code castes the `labelBarButtonItem` pulls out the `customView` then castes that. Then to get the label you can access it by:

```
UILabel *companyLabel = (UILabel*)[labelBarButtonView viewWithTag:tag];
```